# проблемы со звуком в Windows

Tags: аудио

Не знаю, адекватно ли тут постить такое, извиняюсь.
Добрый, не отвечает служба звука, обновление драйверов не помогло. Воспользовался MediaCreationTool, но и она не помогла, выкинула, также заходил в службы и в ручную включал, выключал, обновлял Windwos Audio, но все равно не как, проблема также не в наушниках и не в микрофоне.

Comment: Вам лучше в компьютерный сервис обратиться, на расстоянии вам вряд ли кто-нибудь поможет.